# Include in Entity Framework and Cosmos DB

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a problem with Entity Framework and Cosmos DB.

When I use `.Include` on an entity like this:

```
 public async Task<People[]> GetAllPeopleAsync()
 { 
     IQueryable<People> query = _context.Peoples.Include(p => p.Info);
     return await query.ToArrayAsync();            
 }
```

I get this error:

> Banco De dados Falhos The LINQ expression 'LeftJoin, TransparentIdentifier>(outer: DbSet, inner: DbSet, 
>           outerKeySelector: (p) => Property>(p, "Id"), 
>           innerKeySelector: (i) => Property>(i, "PeopleId"), 
>           resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier(
>               Outer = o, 
>               Inner = i
>           ))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Saving data is working normally as SQL:

```
public void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
     _context.Add(entity);
}

public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
{
     return (await _context.SaveChangesAsync()) > 0;
}
```

My entities:

```
public class People
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public Info Info { get; set; }    
}

public class Info
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string Street { get; set; }
     public string Number { get; set; }
     public Guid PeopleId { get; set; }
     public People People { get; }
}
```

To solve this problem I made a function to get info from `PeopleId` and then put it in `People` and it worked as I needed:

```
public async Task<Info[]> GetInfoByPepleIdAsync(Guid guidPeople)
{ 
    IQueryable<Info> query = _context.Infos.Where(i => i.PeopleId == guidPeople);
    return await query.ToArrayAsync();
}
```

The `GetAllPeopleAsync` function looks like this:

```
public async Task<People[]> GetAllPeopleAsync()
{ 
   IQueryable<People> query = _context.Peoples;
   var Peoples = await query.ToArrayAsync();

   foreach(People p in Peoples) 
   {
       var Infos = await GetInfoByPepleIdAsync(p.Id);
       p.Info = Infos.FirstOrDefault();
   }

   return Peoples;            
 }
```

I would like to know if there is any method that works like include in CosmosDB?

If there is no equivalent method, this method is viable or I will have some performance problem or something?

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019-12-03, Include and Join are not supported by the EF Core Cosmos DB Provider.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/limitations

<strike>You can track the outstanding issues on Github to see if/when it gets implemented for EF Core 3.1. You might even get early access with a preview release.</strike> Include was not released with 3.1. You can still track the progress on that feature here:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+Cosmos+in%3Atitle+label%3Atype-enhancement+sort%3Areactions-%2B1-desc

Earlier this year, Julie Lerman posted a blog showing roughly how Include is expected to work with Cosmos. If the implementation resembles that preview, EF will add something similar to a foreign key when EF infers there are graph/node style relationships between entities in the context.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/january/data-points-a-peek-at-the-ef-core-cosmos-db-provider-preview